# Model has a field which is an array of strings, how can I find all records that contain a certain string in the array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My model has a field called `user_ids`, which is an array of strings. How can I find all of the records which include a certain string, `string_1`, in `user_ids`?

I'm using Rails 3.0.1 & Ruby 1.9.2p0.

Comment: ActiveRecord or MongoID? If AR, why do you use serialization instead of 1:n relationship?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this scope: 
**scope** :some_scope_name, lambda {|user_id| where(["user_ids RLIKE ?", user_id])}
I used this type of scope in project, where I have to find all records with list_ids column match some criteria.

.. or you can use find_by_sql method with same SQL: ["user_ids RLIKE ?", criteria]